# From which Android version is mandatory to have Trusty TEE security OS?

Tags: android, security, tee

I'm trying to find out what is the minimum Android version (API level) for having Trusty TEE security layer mandatory on the device. Does anybody knows this information?

I've tried to find out over the Android official documentation, but it has lacks of information in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Android Marshmallow and above.

Comment: Any reference from official site?

Comment: @BakaWaii it is based on 'isInsideSecureHardware()' see reference here-> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyInfo.html#isInsideSecureHardware()